# Присвоение каждого первого элемента к X и каждого второго к Y Python opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, opencv

есть скрипт который ищет контуры фигуры и выводит их в качестве массива array,я немного переделал,убрав некоторые "лишние" символы и вывел в txt файл получилось это:
15  54  15 142 182 142 182  54 22  62  23  61 174  61 175  62 175 134 174 135  23 135  22 134

это координаты контуров,как я могу присвоить X-су значение 15 а Y-ку значение 54 итак далее?

Comment: `"есть скрипт который ищет контуры фигуры и выводит их в качестве массива array"` - этот массив и есть массив координат, который вы ищете - в первом столбце координаты по оси `X`, во втором по `Y`

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = list(map(int, '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8'.split()))

# 1, Обычный счетчик и немного арифметики
for k in range(len(arr) // 2):
    x, y = arr[2 * k], arr[2 * k + 1]
    print(x, y)

# 2, «Срезы»
for x, y in zip(arr[::2], arr[1::2]):
    print(x, y)

# Справка
print( arr[::2] )  # 1 3 5 7
print( arr[1::2] ) # 2 4 6 8
```

`arr[start : stop : step]` — Такое выражение создает новый массив, вырезая из него соответствующие элементы, начиная с позиции `start`, до `stop` не включительно, с шагом `step`. В случае их отсутствия, значения по умолчанию: `[0 : len() : 1]`

Comment: Правильнее сказать, что срез копирует, а иначе у новичка может возникнуть неверное понимание.